# How do I hash a password when sent to mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm quite new to JavaFX and mysql. I made a register form which allows a user to register. The details are sent to a mysql database. I wanted to hash the password so its more secure. Below is the code where ive tried to hash the password so when it goes to the mysql database, it's secure. Unfortunately I'm still having trouble getting it going. Any help would be great! Code:

```
 public void signUpUser(User user) {

        String insertNew = "INSERT INTO latesttable (FirstName, LastName, email, password)\n" +
                "VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getDbConnection().prepareStatement(insertNew);

            preparedStatement.setString(1,user.getFirstName());
            preparedStatement.setString(2,user.getLastName());
            preparedStatement.setString(3,user.getEmail());
            preparedStatement.setString(4,user.getPassword());

            preparedStatement.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

private void createUser() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler();


        String passwordToHash = passwordField.getText();
        String salt = getSalt();
        String securePassword = get_SHA_256_SecurePassword(passwordToHash, salt);
        System.out.println(securePassword);

        String name = firstNameField.getText();
        String lastName = lastNameField.getText();
        String email = emailField.getText();
        String password = passwordField.getText();

        User user = new User(name,lastName,email,password);

        databaseHandler.signUpUser(user);

    }

    private static String getSalt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        byte[] salt = new byte[16];
        sr.nextBytes(salt);
        return salt.toString();
    }

    private static String get_SHA_256_SecurePassword(String passwordToHash,
                                                     String salt) {
        String generatedPassword = null;
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            md.update(salt.getBytes());
            byte[] bytes = md.digest(passwordToHash.getBytes());
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16)
                        .substring(1));
            }
            generatedPassword = sb.toString();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return generatedPassword;
    }
}
```

Comment: *Unfortunately I'm still having trouble getting it going. Any help would be great!* That's very woolly. What is your actual problem?

Comment: It doesn't work. When the password is sent to the database, it hasn't been hashed.

Comment: Few things: (1) Make sure to specify the charset when converting strings to and from bytes; (2) The salt is made up of 16 _random_ bytes, so I would avoid converting it to a `String` "directly"; (3) You have to store the salt as well so that you can properly hash the password when the user tries to log in some time after signing up.

Comment: "_When the password is sent to the database, it hasn't been hashed_" – This is understandable, given you gave the `User` instance `password` instead of `securePassword`.

Comment: Thanks Slaw, I will make the amendments now.

Comment: **SHA2-256 IS NOT A SUITABLE PASSWORD HASH**. It is a high-speed hash. It is not resistant to brute-force attacks, and has effectively *zero* security value. **Use [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).**

Comment: Yep Ive just spotted that. Altering it now.

Comment: Besides it has very little to do with your question, I highly recommend you to start using JavaFX with maven. The way you are doing stuff is very, very old and outdated. Switching to spring Data JPA and Maven would allow you to the same you did in your MRE code, but with only a half the code you used, twice faster